# Why am I getting ClassNotFoundException when calling Class.forName() on a class that exists in a different module

Tags: android, android-module

So I just moved an activity into our first dynamicModule.  I'm trying to navigate to that activity with the following code:

```
    private enum class ACTIVITIES(val location: String) {
  EXAMPLE_ACTIVITY("com.example.feature_member_home.ExampleActivity"),//com.example.feature_member_home
  REFERRAL_SELECTION_ACTIVITY("com.sofi.mobile.feature_example.ReferralSelectionActivity")//com.sofi.mobile.feature_referrals.ReferralSelectionActivity
}

@Throws(LinkageError::class, ExceptionInInitializerError::class, ClassNotFoundException::class)
fun locateReferralSelectionActivity(context: Context): Intent {
  try {
    return Intent(context, Class.forName(ACTIVITIES.REFERRAL_SELECTION_ACTIVITY.location))
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

but the line `Class.forName(ACTIVITIES.REFERRAL_SELECTION_ACTIVITY.location)` gives an error `ClassNotFoundException on path DexPathList`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: With the comment, are you typo package name with `feature_referrals` & `feature_example`?

Comment: @NamNH no I've double and triple checked the package name.

Comment: Hm, because I saw that `com.sofi.mobile.feature_example.ReferralSelectionActivity` && your comment `//com.sofi.mobile.feature_referrals.ReferralSelectionActivity` . In this case, you may try to `invalidate cache & restart android studio` or enable `multiDexEnabled` in your app `build.gradle` file.